# Why the differences when converting Local Time to GMT?

Tags: java, android, jodatime, android-calendar

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class DefaultChecks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

        Calendar presentCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        System.out.println("With Cal.."+dateFormatGmt.format(presentCal.getTime()));

        dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        String currentDateTimeString = dateFormatGmt.format(new Date());

        System.out.println("With format.."+currentDateTimeString);

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
With Cal..2014-11-14T12:50:23.400Z
With format..2014-11-14T07:20:23.400Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date is an instant in time, and your `TimeZone`(s) are different between the two format calls. Change it to

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    Calendar presentCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // <-- here
    System.out.println("With Cal.."
            + dateFormatGmt.format(presentCal.getTime())); // <-- you use it 
                                                           // here.
    String currentDateTimeString = dateFormatGmt.format(new Date());
    System.out.println("With format.." + currentDateTimeString);
```

And I get the correct output here.

Comment: So setting the timezone to "GMT" in `Calendar presentCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` will not change the TimeZone to "GMT" ? Only `dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` can do that ?

Comment: @VedPrakash No. Changing your local timezone can do that. A Date is a representation of an instant in time as some number of milliseconds since epoch, it has no inherent timezone (or rather it's GMT). It's only when you format it for output (or parse it for input) that you affect the *displayed* value. Like, what's `System.out.println(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1);`? Computers don't always act like you might naively expect.